# C# IP Range Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to exclude content from my *.aspx, for users in a certain IP Address range.

```
string ipRange = @"^12\.345\.678\.(2(4[0-9]|5[0-5]))$";
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Request.UserHostAddress.ToString(), System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(ipRange))){//BLOCKED CONTENT GOES HERE}
```

I'm pretty weak at regex, so I cheated and got the pattern using Google's [IP Range Tool](http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034771&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-e9afkbcgrfjn&cbrank=1)

In this example it's not effectively blocking 12.345.678.254

What am I missing?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but `12.345.678.254` is not a valid IP address...

Comment: Why are you escaping? Your regex pattern is fine... just don't escape it.

Comment: @DanBreen +1 for the eye for detail :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be escaping the regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(ipRange)
```

should be:

```
ipRange
```

If you escape it, all characters become literal, so for example `[0-9]` no longer matches a digit in 0 to 9, but instead matches the string consisting of the five characters `[`, `0`, `-`, `9`, `]`.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the answer, and the explanation!  I read somewhere I needed the escape to handle the backslashes in my regex.  Guess the <code>.escape()</code> wasn't necessary for my implementation.