# Exclude range of IP addresses from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a data table that includes a column holding IP addresses. I need to be able to filter the rows and remove all rows where IP address is in the range of, say, from 10.20.1.xxx to 10.20.15.xxx as well as 10.20.61.xxx. (i.e. exclude 10.20.1.xxx, 10.20.2.xxx, ..., 10.20.14.xxx, 10.20.15.xxx and 10.20.61.xxx).

Comment: It seems that you need to treat this column as a normal number. Perhaps having another column with the corresponding translation of your IP in a decimal number and then executing the query on this second column could be faster (the column should be set at insertion time of course)

Comment: @Steve for my own edumacation, would it be too slow to select all, explode by `.` and delete from table if in certain range?

Comment: Well, in code could be done in a relatively easy way, but I was under the impression that the poster wants to do this directly with a query on the database table. As usual with performances, first measure then talk.

Comment: @Steve can you give me an example of how set the query, assuming this second column is added to database table? I am displaying data in a grid from a set of facilities; user can select to exclude a particular facility and this facility has IP addresses in the range I specified. This is what I need to implement.

Comment: Also, when you say add another column, do you mean for a row that contains an IP address of 10.20.2.123, I should record the same IP as 102002123? Can this filtering not be done using regular expression, Linq, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following,

```
        DataTable dt; //your datatable here
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(dr["Column name of your IP"].ToString(), "regex to check  IP") == false)
            {
               //Delete that row or something
            }
            else
            {
               //Do something else
            }
        }
        DataTable tempTable = dv.ToTable();
       //where temptable is your sorted and updated datatable
```

You can store this inside a method and call it to perform a check wherever you are binding or before that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ip LIKE '10.20.1.%'
```

or

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ip LIKE '10.20.%'
```

Linq

Without any code from you on how you're getting data from DB this will just get you a list of rows to be deleted, you can take it from there

```
var itemsToDelete = someList.Where(x => x.Ip.StartsWith("10.20.1"));
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, but I don't want to delete everything that starts with 10.20.1. I have a range, say, from 10.20.1 to 10.20.15 plus one like 10.20.61. So, I don't want to delete 10.20.16.xxx or 10.20.29.xxx. Can it be something like a "From" to "To" range?

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. Perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054352/c-sharp-ip-range-filter it's a regex solution, don't think it'll be the most efficient if you have to loop through al of the rows. Also i saw you were thinking about removing the . this might cause you problems

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Newtable = (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
    where (
        Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("IP").Split('.')[2]) > 15 &&  
        Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("IP").Split('.')[2]) != 61)
    select r).CopyToDataTable();
```